# Plugins: Openlayers and OSM-Download QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Where are the Plugins for Downloading OSM-Data and the Openlayer-Plugin (with MORE than OSM). These are the most-importent plugins for me! Gone? Then I go back to QGIS 2 ;(

[image: OSM-Download]

[image: OpenLayer]

Comment: For some reason the developers have added "Early adopter release" in the splash screen.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange. Please not that the format of this Q&A site requires us to stick to one question per thread. Please edit your post to focus on one question only. Feel free to post any additional question in additional threads.

Comment: You can use OSMDownloader to download .osm files and load them automatically into QGIS3. I just finished the porting. Check here how to use it: https://github.com/lcoandrade/OSMDownloader/wiki

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All plugins from earlier versions must be updated to be compatible with QGIS 3.0. If your favorite plugins are missing, be patient and wait for the plugin developers to update them. 3.0 hasn't been out very long.

Regarding the openlayers plugin, there's a much better option already updated for QGIS 3.0: QuickMapServices.

Comment: Yes - in no circumstance should you ever use OpenLayers plugin. Always use QuickMapServices instead.

Comment: And for downloading OSM data as vector, QGIS 3 has dropped the builtin downloader. You should use the QuickOSM plugin instead.